# How can I replace "/" with "\/" in a string?

Tags: c#, string

I would like to do the following:

```
if (string.Contains("/"))
{
  string.Replace("/", "\/"); //this isn't valid
}
```

I've tried

```
string.Replace("/", "\\/");
```

but this gives me what I started with. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, which means that any modification you do to a string results in a new one, you should assign the result of the `Replace` method:

```
if (myString.Contains("/"))
{
  myString  = myString.Replace("/", "\\/"); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) *returns* the string with replacements made - it doesn't change the string itself. It can't; strings are immutable. You need something like:

```
text = text.Replace("/", "\\/");
```

(In future examples, it would be helpful if you could use valid variable names btw. It means that those wishing to respond with working code can use the same names as you've used.)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a verbatim string literal

```
string.Replace("/", @"\");
```

Comment: You mean "verbatim string literal" - anything in double quotes is a string literal.